# How to get only positive numbers in python

Tags: python, input

I want to get only positive numbers in python .

and if the user enter a negative number the program show an error message .

should I code lots of conditions like

if this : do this

if that : do that

and so on .

or is there another way for this ?

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far in attempt to solve this problem, and point out the part that's not working?

Comment: You should at least show your attempt that uses "lots of if function"

Answer (score 0):

Use `abs(x)` Python native function.

EDIT: if you want to raise an error, instead, I would make use of assertions (example taken from [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/python/python-assert):

```
x = 0
assert x > 0, 'Only positive numbers are allowed'
print('x is a positive number.')
```

Comment: This will not show an error message if `x` is negative. It will simply convert `x` to a positive number the same distance from zero, which may not be what OP wants.

Comment: I think you're right. I would use an assertion then:

Answer (score 0):

You can use just an if statement like the code below:

```
n = float(input("Enter a positive number: "))
if num <= 0:
    raise ValueError("Please enter only positive numbers")
```

If the number is not a positive one you can manage as you prefer. In the example I put a raise, but you can also use a print statement with the message or an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Not sur to understand your question,

you only need to do `if x >= 0:` if you want to check if x is positive or negative

Answer (score 0):

Simple options to achieve this can be

- if input_num < 0
- if abs(input_num) == input_num
  In 1st case, you check if given number is less than 0 (it is negative)
  In 2nd case, you use abs() function which gives a positive number from a negative or positive number. e.g. abs(-2) # returns 2